# How do you use pure mp3 encoding in html

Tags: javascript, php, html, mp3, mpeg

I have recently been working on a private project, and I cannot find any answers as to how to use put mpeg encoding for my audio. When I say pure mpeg encoding, I do not mean

```
<audio src="audio.mp3" autoplay controls></audio>
```

I mean like this

```
<audio encoding="...�I^L��s ۾^]�..." autoplay controls></audio>
```

Do you know if it is possible? If so, how do I do it? I am open to ideas using HTML, JS, or PHP.

Thank you in advance,
CamelInATardis

Comment: [data uri](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme). whether the browser's player will allow that is to you to figure out.

Comment: `audio.src=URL.createObjectURL(blob)`;

Comment: You can use base-64 encoding in a data URI, but you really shouldn't do this.  You're adding 33% overhead in bandwidth alone.